# How to make status bar title color white in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have googled, but they are so complicated. I set the status bar status in AppDelegate:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

but no work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply do this in a swift file.
You can override this function in a viewcontroller class.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

You don't need to set any value in info.plist.
Just above function will do.

But if you are going to change every view controller in white status colored, then you will need to set in AppDelegate.
Hope to make sense.